# How to convert an image to a dicom image?

Tags: python, opencv, scipy

How are JPEGs and PNGs converted to dicom readable images? There doesn't seem to be information about that on the internet. I've seen posts about converting dicom images to JPEGs, but not the other way round.

Comment: https://imebra.com maybe

Answer (score 2):

You can use pydicom https://github.com/darcymason/pydicom that allows you to read, modify and write DICOM files with Python code.

Comment: Yeah, I went through it, but there's no examples or documentation about how I can write dicom files.